# How to configure ambient framework within a Tridion CWA web app

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery, ambient

I'm adding ambient framework within an existing Tridion CWA Java web application and I have some questions regarding the mapping of java filters (ambient framework filter vs CWA filters)

In the SDL CWA 2011 SP1 documentation (online portal) they say:

> 16 - If you intend to use the Ambient Data Framework in combination
>   with CWA, also open the web.xml file in the WEB-INF/ folder and add
>   the following:
>
> ```
> <filter>
>   <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
>   <filter-class>com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter</filter-class>
> </filter>
> <filter-mapping>
>   <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
>   <servlet-name>Content Delivery Web service</servlet-name>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

I don't understand this filter-mapping. In my web-app there is no Content Delivery Web Service.

**My questions:**

**1 - Does it means Ambient Data Framework requires the installation of the Content Delivery Web Service to work** ? For me the filter-mapping of Ambient Data filter should be the same as the mapping of CWA request filter

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>cwa</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>my-mapping</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>my-maping</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

**2 - What about PageFileDistributionFilter & BinaryFileDistributionFilter ?**

**3 - Is there a recommanded filter order ? CWA filters configured before Ambient Data filter for ex ?**

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Sébastien - You seem to have a great Tridion knowledge based on some of your answers here on SO. Would you consider committing to the SDL Tridion Area 51 proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 using your SO account - The SDL Tridion community really needs all the support we can get. Thanks

Comment: Hi Chris. It's done ;)

Answer (score 4):

On #1: It's a documentation defect, it should be this instead:

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

On #2, yes you still need those two of course.

On #3, I *suspect* you should have the Ambient Framework loaded first, as that is the recommendation for non-CWA web apps (your filters could use the Ambient Framework, for instance)